# Which is better for Monero mining: AMD Threadripper or Intel i9 7900x?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, mining-hardware

I have seen a lot of reviews of this two processors but they have focused on movie editing, videogames, compresion, etc. But I haven't seen a good benchmark particularly on monero mining. I know that is depends on a lot of external factors too, but only in terms of processing power and how to handle threads, temperature, etc. which on is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMD Threadripper is clearly better. Take a look at this [german article](https://www.computerbase.de/2018-02/mining-monero-cpu). If you don't understand german, take a look at the table with the number of threads. The more threads the better.

On the [second page](https://www.computerbase.de/2018-02/mining-monero-cpu/2) you will then see the relevant charts

Here are the details from that article

Cache size and optimal number of threads

```
CPU                             L2-Cache    L3-Cache    Optimal # Threads
AMD Ryzen 3 1200                2 MB        8 MB        4
AMD Ryzen 5 1600X               3 MB        16 MB       8
AMD Ryzen 7 1800X               4 MB        16 MB       8
AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1920X    6 MB        32 MB       16
AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X    9 MB        32 MB       16
Intel Core i7-7700K             1 MB        8 MB        4
Intel Core i7-8700K             1,5 MB      8 MB        6
Intel Core i9-7900X             10 MB       13,75 MB    10
```

Hashes per Second

```
CPU                                 H/s
AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1920X        1.139
AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X        1.009
Intel Core i9-7900X                 533
AMD Ryzen 7 1800X                   495
AMD Ryzen 5 1600X                   429
Intel Core i7-8700K                 339
Intel Core i7-7700K                 218
AMD Ryzen 3 1200                    197
```

Power consumption in Watt

```
CPU                                 Watt
AMD Ryzen 3 1200                    21
Intel Core i7-7700K                 27
AMD Ryzen 5 1600X                   48
Intel Core i7-8700K                 52
AMD Ryzen 7 1800X                   58
AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1920X        69
Intel Core i9-7900X                 80
AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X        87
```

Hashes per Watt

```
CPU                             H/s
AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1920X    14,6
AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X    13,1
AMD Ryzen 3 1200                9,4
AMD Ryzen 5 1600X               8,9
AMD Ryzen 7 1800X               8,5
Intel Core i7-7700K             8,1
Intel Core i9-7900X             6,7
Intel Core i7-8700K             6,5
```

Comment: thanks, even I don't understand german, the tables were very useful. But then, is Threadripper 1920x better than Threadripper 1950x??

Comment: Actually, yes it is :) More Hashes per second and also not as much power consumption

Comment: Endogen, can you please embed some information from the article in case the link ever goes down?  This answer should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: I added all the necessary informations